# Rounded corner Card Widget with right border in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have to create a Card like this:

[image]

I had written below code to achieve the desired UI, but it didn't work as expected.

```dart
Card(
  elevation: 5,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
      topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
    side: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.green)),
  child: ListTile(),
)
```

The code above produced this:

[image]

Whereas using the code below:

```dart
Card(
  elevation: 5,
  shape: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 5)),
  child: ListTile(),
)
```

Generated this output:

[image]

How can I create the required UI in flutter?

Comment: Maybe you can try wrapping your card with ClipOval

Answer (score 95):

Use the shape parameter in the Card widget, example:

```
Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      child: Container() )
```

Answer (score 53):

I have used ClipPath to achieve the UI asked in the question, check out the below code.

```
Card(
     elevation: 2,
     child: ClipPath(
       child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 5))),
            ),
       clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3))),
               ),
    )
```

This gives the below output,
[image]

If there is a better way to achieve said result kindly do answer.

Comment: @david-bronn, See my answer please, as I was having problems in implementation the way you did. I was having white corners for card.

Answer (score 14):

This solution worked for me. If we remove the `shape` property from the card, it leaves behind rectangular white corners. No limitation of `elevation` whatsoever.

```
              Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                shadowColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                elevation: 15,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 180,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                            left: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 15)),
                        color: Colors.yellowAccent.shade100,
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Container()),
                ),
              )
```

[image]

Comment: Off all the answers I tried out, this was the only one that worked correctly.

Comment: Same here, thx @Ian

Answer (score 7):

You should place your `Card` inside a `ClipRRect` widget :

```
     return ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 5,
                shape: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 5)),
                child: ListTile(),
       ),
     );
```

But I advise you to reduce the value of `elevation` because it is distorting the small circular borders.

Comment: This, regrettably, just clips the card and shadow, which does not reproduce the effect of a rounded card.

Comment: This destroys the material behaviour of the card. Don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

For me, all the solutions using clipping cut off some of the shadow. Anyway, I found an easier solution imo:

Wrap the card's child around a Container widget. Specify the rounded rectangle border for the card, then the colored border side for the container.

```
Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)),
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 8)
        ),
        child: // your card content
    )
)
```

Comment: Regrettably the border side extends from the card body into the outside of the rounded corner.

Answer (score 3):

1. For `Right` curved border, you can use:

```
            child: Card(
                elevation: 6.0,
                color: Colors.amber,
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 14),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Output:

[image]

Extra: You can create `rounded border` using

```
            child: Card(
                elevation: 6.0,
                color: Colors.amber,
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                        right: Radius.circular(20),
                      )),
                ),
              ),
```

Output:

[image]

---

2. For `Left` curved border, you can use:

```
              child: Card(
                elevation: 6.0,
                color: Colors.amber,
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Output:

[image]

Extra: You can create rounded border using:

```
              child: Card(
                elevation: 6.0,
                color: Colors.amber,
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                        left: Radius.circular(20),
                      )),
                ),
              ),
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `clipBehavior` in the `Card` and move the BorderSide to a `Container`.

```
      Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                      right: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 5))),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Card you could also use a Container to achieve this, you can use the `gradient` property on `BoxDecoration`. The `stops` property is going to determine the width of your border. Then you can add your colors and have a nice border.

For the rounded edges you can just use the `borderRadius` property.

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 4.0,
            vertical: 8.0,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 8.0,
            vertical: 12.0,
          ),
          child: Text('A "card" with rounded edges and a border'),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              stops: [0.015, 0.015],
              colors: [
                Colors.blue,
                Colors.white,
              ],
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(5.0),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                blurRadius: 4.0,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 1.5),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

[Result from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGkI4.png)