# Flutter Unable to create corner curved color padding

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, card

**Orange color corner curve padding** not archive but here I get straight line only suggest any check my code..!

[image: Check the below image orange corner rounder curve]

```
Widget build(Context context) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 6.0),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 6.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      left: BorderSide(
                        color:  Colors.transparent,
                        width: 2.0,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corner Card Widget with right border in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316539/rounded-corner-card-widget-with-right-border-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use

```
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 6.0),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 6.0,
                color: Colors.amber,
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8), //  This will specifiy the width of the curved border 
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                        left: Radius.circular(20),
                      )),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: its also like straight line, see the above posted image (zoom it) rounded corner curve not perfectly achieve

Comment: @DGAD , yess i looked into it , and made the required edit , Now check out the code.

Comment: I have added pointer where you can define the width of the curved border, you can adjust it based on your needs

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this widget,

```dart
class MyTaskItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  //final MyTaskDetailItem myLeadDetailItem;

  const MyTaskItemWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6.0,
      color: Colors.amber, //curve color
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      ),

      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0),// here the thickness 
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```