# Flutter - Create custom label with specific curved background

Tags: flutter, shapes, card

I need to create specific curved background label on the left side of the Card element.
Look on attached image.
[image]

What is the best way to achieve this?
Thanks

I was searching in the internet but I haven't found similar solution. The only related post which I found is this one - [Rounded corner Card Widget with right border in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316539/rounded-corner-card-widget-with-right-border-in-flutter)

But it's not exactly what I want.

Comment: make a custom `ShapeBorder` class and return a result of [roundPolyyon](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L24) from `getOuterPath` method - there are couple of examples in the file I linked